# Understanding the behaviour of Function.ScalarVector

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a use case where I would like to pass two arguments to a function generated by `Function.ScalarVector` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/function-scalarvector).

I would like the second argument to, optionally, capture *two or more* columns of a table, e.g. `ScalarFun([Col1], {[Col2], [Col3]})`. I would expect this to pass a list of lists to the function itself. Alas, it does not.

Consider this example, if I define a function to simply capture the generated input list (which we'd normally pass on to a function doing something useful with the list) we can see that passing a list of two values and a *concatenation* of two values generate very different behaviour:

```
let
    ScalarFun = 
        Function.ScalarVector(
            type function (col as any) as any,
            (t) => 
                let 
                    buf = Table.Buffer(t) 
                in 
                    List.Transform(buf[col], each List.Distinct(buf[col]))
        ),
    TestTable = Table.FromColumns(
        {{"a","b","c"}, {"x","y","z"}}, 
        {"Col2", "Col3"}
    ),
    #"List syntax" = Table.AddColumn(
        TestTable, 
        "List1", 
        each Text.Combine(List.First(ScalarFun({[Col2],[Col3]})), ";")
    ),
    #"Concactenation syntax" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"List syntax", 
        "List2", 
        each Text.Combine(ScalarFun([Col2] & [Col3]), ";")
    )
in
    #"Concactenation syntax"
```

Given this output I can see that the syntax where we combine two values into a list `ScalarFun([Col1], {[Col2], [Col3]})` actually operate row by row. Concatenating two text values however works just fine (the function gets passed a list containing the entire column).

[image]

A list is just a value like any other, so I don't understand why my preferred syntax doesn't work?

**Update:**

It's clear to me that the function does not behave in the way I anticipated due to [lazy evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/evaluation-model#lazy-and-eager-evaluation). I see the same issue if I try to use a record. Passing a list in this rather convoluted way 'works' however:

`Text.Split(Text.Combine({[Col2],[Col3]}, ";"),";")`

I'm not going to post this as an answer because I don't fully understand why this (silently, without an error) breaks the intended behaviour of `Function.ScalarVector`.

Answer (score 0):

A list of lists is not the same as concatenated lists so I don't see any reason to expect them to behave the same way.

```
{TestTable[Col2], TestTable[Col3]} = {{a,b,c},{x,y,z}}
TestTable[Col2] & TestTable[Col3]  = {a,b,c,x,y,z}
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by behave. By behaviour I mean that the scalar function gets passed a list of every column value as opposed to each row value(s).

The scalar function gets passed ```{"ax","by","cz"}``` when the argument is the concatenated strings (see ```List2``` in the example output). I expected that with the list example it would be passed ```{{"a", "x"}, {"b", "y"}, {"c", "z"}}```.

Comment: There's also the additional complication that ScalarFun is expecting a column name but you're passing something else entirely.

Comment: Does it though? It should expect whatever type is specified in ```type function (col as any) as any```. Regardless, the (text) combination of _two columns_ work as expected so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the list example to pass the arguments as

```
{{"a", "x"}, {"b", "y"}, {"c", "z"}}
```

you will need to create a Col4 combining Col2 and Col3, as the next line of M code

```
AddColumn_to_testtable = Table.AddColumn(TestTable,"Col4", each [Col2]&[Col3]),
List3 = Table.AddColumn(#"Concactenation syntax", "List3", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(ScalarFun([Col4]), each Text.Combine(_,"")),";"))
```

[image: PrintScreen]

The behavior of the ScalarVector function when you pass the arguments as a list is different than when you pass the argument as a list of lists. In List1 (list of lists) for row 1 only past the first element in the argument list for row 2 the second and so on. If instead you use the Col4 in the argument as show in List3, you will pass for every row the same value which is the entire list (as occurred in your List2 example).

Hope this brings a bit more clarity why the List example did not behave as you originally expected.